# How to vectorize modifying elements in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Given a:

`tf.tensor A` with shape `N*M`, (`A = tf.zeros((N, M))`)
  `tf.tensor` `indices` with shape `N*k` (k<=M). Each `ith` row contains some indices of tensor `A`
  `tf.tensor upates` with shape `N*K` . Each `ith` row contains values to be used to updates tensor `A`

Goal: update the elements of `A`  where their indices exist in `indices`, with values in `updates`

**Use tf.scatter_nd in a loop**

```
result = []
for idx in range(N):
    index = tf.reshape(indices[idx], (-1, 1))
    updates = tf.convert_to_tensor(updates[idx])
    scatter = tf.scatter_nd(index, updates, shape=tf.constant([M]))
    target.append(scatter)
result = tf.stack(result, axis=0)
```

This loop is obviously working for `N` being small.

Question: How to vectorize this to run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first tensor `A` is always made of zeros, you can do that with one call to [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

indices = ... # shape: (n, k)
updates = ... # shape: (n, k)
s = tf.shape(indices, out_type=indices.dtype)
n = s[0]
k = s[1]
idx_row = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(n), 1), (1, k))
idx_full = tf.stack([idx_row , indices], axis=-1)
result = tf.scatter_nd(idx_full, updates, [n, m])
```

If the initial `A` contains something else, you would do essentially the same but using [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) instead:

```py
A = ... # shape: (n, m)
result = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(A, idx_full, updates)
```